# Rails AJAX updating a nested model trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, model

I have an app with the models Game, Square, Ownedsq, and User, and I am trying to update a square's :user_id within a game. I have been trying this for hours now, I believe the model relationships are correct and I am just missing something small so I appreciate any help.

Currently clicking the update ownedsq submit button does not change the user_id. There are no errors, nothing gets updated, nothing happens on the server.

**games/show.html.erb**
(Rows of 10 Ownedsq)

```
<div class="squareBoard">
    <% @ownedsqs.each_slice(10) do |slice| %>
        <div class='row'>
            <% slice.each do |s| %>
                <%= div_for s, class: 'sq' do |buy| %>
                    <%= s.user_id %>
                    <%= render "buyownedsq", s: buy %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**_buyownedsq.html.erb** (clicking should set the ownedsq user_id to current user)

```
<%= simple_fields_for s, remote: true do |z| %>
    <%= z.input :user_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value:current_user.id} %>
    <%= z.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**games_controller.rb**

```
def show
    require 'enumerator'
    @user = current_user
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @squares = Square.all
    @square = Square.find(params[:id])
    @ownedsqs = Ownedsq.all
end
```

**ownedsqs_controller.rb**

```
def update
    @ownedsq.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        if @ownedsq.update_attributes(params[:ownedsq])
            format.html {redirect_to game_path}
            format.json {head :no_content}
        else
            format.html {redirect_to :back}
        end  
    end 
end
```

**Game.rb**

```
has_many :ownedsqs
has_many :squares, through: :ownedsqs
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

accepts_nested_attributes_for :ownedsqs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :squares
```

**Square.rb**

```
has_many :ownedsqs
has_many :users, through: :ownedsqs
has_many :games, through: :ownedsqs

accepts_nested_attributes_for :ownedsqs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
accepts_nested_attributes_for :games
```

**Ownedsq.rb**

```
belongs_to :square
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :game

validates_uniqueness_of :square_id, scope: :game_id
```

**User.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :games
has_many :ownedsqs
has_many :squares, through: :ownedsqs

accepts_nested_attributes_for :ownedsqs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :squares
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems here for you to look at:

1. How do you receive the `params[:id]` of the `ownedsq`?
2. You can easily get rid of the view-level `user_id` reference
3. Your remote calls won't raise an error directly; they'll do it through the `network` tab of your browser

---

**Formatting**

I'd just use a simple link / button to send the request to the server:

```
_buyownedsq.html.erb
<%= button_to ownedsq_path(buy.id), method: :put, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, remote: :true %>
```

This will send a request to the server, which you can process like this:

```
#app/controllers/ownedsqs_controller.rb
def update
    @ownedsq = Ownedsq.find(params[:id]) #where do you get the params[:id] var?

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        if @ownedsq.update_attributes(user_id: current_user.id)
            format.html {redirect_to game_path}
            format.json {head :no_content, status: :200}
        else
            format.html {redirect_to :back}
            format.json {status: :500 }
        end  
    end 
end
```

---

**Save**

Your associations look right - I don't presume the `update_attributes` method would get confused / have issues, as you're working directly with the `OwnedSq` model (not using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` etc)